# C# StackTrace not including call to new operator

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace, new-operator

I come from C++ and I don't understand why in C# when I write :

```
class A {
    public A(){ /*here I get the StackTrace */}
    //......other code
    void f(){ A a = new A();
}
```

When I inspect the StackTrace object inside the constructor I can't find the call to the new() operator between "f()" function call and the "A()" constructor.

Why is the the new() operator omitted? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There is no separate `new` function call. Just the constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

My .Net Disassembly skill smay be weak, but here is what I get allocating two different objects:

```
        {
00000022  nop 
            new Object();
00000023  mov         ecx,79B9F5E8h 
00000028  call        FD95FB90 
0000002d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],eax 
00000030  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch] 
00000033  call        76AF49F0 
00000038  nop 
        }
00000039  nop 
        {
0000003a  nop 
            new StringBuilder();
0000003b  mov         ecx,79B9FB78h 
00000040  call        FD95FB90 
00000045  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax 
00000048  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
0000004b  call        76ACF938 
00000050  nop 
        }
```

The way I am interpreting this is that "new X()" evaluates to two seperate calls.  The first might be the "memory allocation" while the second call is the constructor of the object.  I say this because the first method called by both statements is the same (even though they are different types), and the second call in each case is different.

If anyone knows how to verify what these specific addresses evaluate to, I would love to know.